# How to run a particular scenario if it appears in webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I'm running a test case where in some times during logging in OTP is asked and sometimes not.
So how can i handle it when it appears and in case it doesn't appear. I mean if it appears the code to handle should run and in case it dosent appear the code(webdriver) should perform it's usual operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "store xpath count" command to store count of elements by xpath to variable.
Next step use this variable in "if"

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by first fetching that element in a list and then check if the size of the list is greater than zero. If the size>0, it means the element is present on the page else it is not present.

Your code should be like:

```
List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.id("Enter the id here"));
if(elementList.size()>0){
    // Element is present, operate on the element
}

// Element is not present, write your code which should run in every case
```

Comment: put the above code in try catch otherwise in case element is not found the code will give exception

Comment: @salsinga No it will not, if the list size is less than 0, the code wont enter the if block and no exception would be there. I have used this way infinite times and it works completely fine.